# What is "deuchère" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

In this panel from *Astérix et Cléopâtre*, I saw a word that was not in the dictionary: *deuchère*. I am also not entirely sure about *vé* and *té*, although I assume the joke is that the letters V and T are the approximate shapes the man and then the bird seem to be making with their arms/wings.

[image]

Comment: Je me demande si ce ne serait pas plutôt "peuchère", une interjection utilisée dans quelques régions de France pour exprimer de la pitié ?

Comment: @Alone-zee Peuchère peut  exprimer la pitié mais aussi la surprise (c'est le cas ici) et aussi l'admiration (Oh! peuchère que c'est beau !).

Comment: [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/peuch%C3%A8re) Région. (Provence). Exclam. traduisant la surprise, l'attendrissement, l'admiration ou la pitié.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C'est "[peuchère](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/peuch%C3%A8re)" (le pauvre, le malheureux) et non "deuchère" qui est écrit ici.

Tout comme "[vé](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/v%C3%A9#Interjection)" (regarde), "[té](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A9#Interjection)" (tiens), et "[fada](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fada#Adjectif)" (fou), cela vient de l'[occitan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan), en particulier du [provençal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proven%C3%A7al) et du [languedocien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languedocien).

La blague est que les ouvriers venant du sud de l’Égypte sont traduits avec des mots typiques du français parlé au sud de la France. D'ailleurs, un lecteur français lira probablement ça avec [l'accent du Sud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYTNBUpuTc8). ^^

Comment: Objection très personnelle à l'emploi du mot patois ayant un double sens en français. Peuchère est un mot d'origine [provençale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proven%C3%A7al) et ne s'emploie pas dans toute l'Occitanie (et pas dans tout le sud de la France), on peut le localiser de la Drôme à l'Ardèche à la Provence et au Languedoc oriental.

Comment: @Laure Toutes mes excuses, n'ayant jamais vécu là-bas je connais pas avec précision où sont employées les expressions. N'hésite pas à corriger ma réponse. Je pense que la blague repose plus sur l'idée qu'on se fait de l'accent du Sud en général, mal connu par le reste de la francophonie.

Comment: Hiya. I've just sent a new email. :)